# integrality of certain rational numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, rational-functions

Let $P,Q\in\mathbb Q[X]$ be relatively prime polynomials ($X$ being an indeterminate). Assume that $Q(0)=1$ and that $P/Q$ is in $\mathbb Z[[X]]$.

Does this imply that $P$ and $Q$ are in $\mathbb Z[X]$?

Comment: Are you familiar with Fatou's Lemma?

Comment: @BillDubuque: Do you mean [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou's_lemma)?

Comment: @Pierrre Not that one, but the one about rational power series. See e.g. [p. 275 of R. P. Stanley, *Enumerative Combinatorics 1*.](http://books.google.co.id/books?id=EvJg1VjIGyMC&pg=PA275) $\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque: As my previous comment suggests, I am not familiar with this Fatou's Lemma. I'll take a close look at it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you cannot access that page in Google Books let me know and I can email a copy.

Comment: I can access the page. Thank you very much again! ... By the way, if you have any idea about [this question](http://mathoverflow.net/q/162162/461), I'd be most grateful!

Comment: Great. Btw, the statement of the result is [here on p. 264.](http://books.google.co.id/books?id=EvJg1VjIGyMC&pg=PA264) Like Gauss's Lemma, there are many variations on Fatou's Lemme in the literature (though it's hard to search for them because of the other one is dominant).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've added it to my list of interesting questions to ponder when I have more spare time.

Comment: I think you're right: the Fatou's Lemma you mention provides immediately an answer to my question. It would be very nice if you could upgrade your comment to an answer.

Comment: A version of the book is available from [this page](http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/ec1/), which belongs to Stanley's website.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for reminding me about the free version.

Comment: Please feel welcome to edit the answer as you like (alas, there is little collaboration on MSE).

Comment: Thanks! But it looks perfect to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a straightforward consequence of *Fatou's Lemma* on rational power series. Here is a statement and proof from R. P. Stanley's [Enumerative Combinatorics, I](http://books.google.co.id/books?id=EvJg1VjIGyMC&pg=PA275) (or see p. 629 of the [free version here)](http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/ec1/)

[image]
[image]

Comment: I've just posted a minor complement to your answer (and fixed a typo).

Answer (score 1):

This is a minor complement to Bill's answer.

The answer to the question is yes. As indicated by Bill, this follows immediately from the statement below, known as Fatou's Lemma:

(1) If $f\in\mathbb Q[[x]]$ has integer coefficients, then there are $P,Q$ in $\mathbb Z[x]$ such that $f=P/Q$, $(P,Q)=1$ in $\mathbb Q[x]$, and $Q(0)=1$.

We start by quoting Stanley:

Define a formal power series $\sum_{n\ge0}a_nx^n$ with integer coefficients to be **primitive** if no integer $d > 1$ divides all the $a_i$. One easily shows that the product of primitive series is primitive.

We claim:

(2) The following conditions on a primitive polynomial $Q\in\mathbb Z[x]$ are equivalent:

(a) $Q(0)=\pm1$,

(b) $1/Q\in\mathbb Z[[x]]$,

(c) $Qg=m$ for some $g$ in $\mathbb Z[[x]]$ and some positive integer $m$.

It is clear that (a) and (b) are equivalent and imply (c). Assuming (c) and writing $g=dh$ where $d$ is a positive integer and $h$ a primitive element of $\mathbb Z[[x]]$, we get $Qh=m/d$. As $Q$ and $h$ are primitive, this yields $m=d$, and thus (b). This proves (2).

Let us prove (1).

We have $f=P/Q$ for some polynomials $P,Q$ in $\mathbb Z[x]$ such that $(P,Q)=1$ in $\mathbb Q[x]$ and no prime number divides every coefficient of $P$ and $Q$. The equality $Qf=P$, which holds in $\mathbb Z[[x]]$, shows that $Q$ is primitive. In view of (2), it suffices to prove (c). There are polynomials $A,B$ in $\mathbb Z[x]$ and a positive integer $m$ such that $AP+BQ=m$. Then (c) holds for $g:=Af+B$.